# Nuxt.js : transition from and to params aren't available on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm using `Nuxt JS` 2.9.1, and am trying to use the transition function. I have some params, but they're not available on page load:

```
export default {
  transition (to, from) {
    if (from.params.id) console.log(from.params.id)
  }
}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Does anyone have a solution for this error?

Comment: I guess your params are not created...In nuxt this is done automaticly based on file name. Is the file you are using named "_id.vue" ?

Comment: Yes, this is how it's setup

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading the page "from" nothing, "from" will be undefined and "To" is defined. If you start navigation "from" will be defined

Comment: Is there a check I can add to check if it's undefined, and if it is, do a default transition?

Comment: You can use this to check for the id   
if(['params', 'id'].reduce((o, k) => (o && o[k] !== 'undefined') ? o[k] : undefined, from) > 0)

Comment: Default transitions can be set in the layout file